AgGrid ^31.2.0 | Typescript Errors Enterprise vs Community
I'm working on setting up a new project that uses AgGrid's react library + enterprise library. I've installed the latest versions of ag-grid-react, ag-grid-community, and ag-grid-enterprise (^31.2.0). Unfortunately, despite them all being the same version (and I made sure to delete the yarn.lock file and re-install) I keep getting odd typescript conflicts.
For instance, if I have a file that exports a bunch of column definitions and attempt to use those with the AgGridReact component, the typescript flags the column definitions as being incompatible. But if I copy and past those same definitions directly into the component property, then it works.
Here's a ClientAgGrid component I'm attempting to create:
export interface ClientDataGridParams extends AgGridReactProps<Client> {
}

export const ClientDataGrid = (params?: ClientDataGridParams) => {
  const [trigger] = ClientsApi.useLazyReadClientsQuery(); // RTK Query

  return (
    <AgGridReact<Client>
      rowModelType="clientSide"

      columnDefs={ClientColumnDefs}

      {...params}
    />
  )
}

And here are the column definitions:
export const ClientColumnDefs: ColDef<Client>[] = [
  {
    headerName: "#",
    sortable: false,
    filter: false,
    floatingFilter: false,
    cellRenderer: RowNumberCellRenderer,
    width: 75,
    pinned: 'left'
  },
  {
    field: 'id',
    hide: true,
    filter: 'text'
  },
  {
    field: 'origin',
    filter: 'text',
  },
  {
    field: 'createdAt',
    headerName: 'Created At',
    filter: 'date',
    cellRenderer: DateTimeCellRenderer
  },
  {
    field: 'updatedAt',
    headerName: 'Updated At',
    filter: 'date',
    cellRenderer: DateTimeCellRenderer
  }
];

export default ClientColumnDefs;

I'm getting the following error when my project compiles....
TS2322: Type 'ColDef<Client, any>[]' is not assignable to type '(ColDef<Client, any> | ColGroupDef<Client>)[]'.
  Type 'ColDef<Client, any>' is not assignable to type 'ColDef<Client, any> | ColGroupDef<Client>'.
    Type 'import("/home/rwilliams/repos/fifthsun/sentinel/node_modules/ag-grid-enterprise/dist/types/core/entities/colDef").ColDef<import("/home/rwilliams/repos/fifthsun/sentinel/src/api/mauthra/admin/Clients/common").Client, any>' is not assignable to type 'import("/home/rwilliams/repos/fifthsun/sentinel/node_modules/ag-grid-community/dist/types/core/entities/colDef").ColDef<import("/home/rwilliams/repos/fifthsun/sentinel/src/api/mauthra/admin/Clients/common").Client, any>'.
      Types of property 'valueGetter' are incompatible.
        Type 'string | import("/home/rwilliams/repos/fifthsun/sentinel/node_modules/ag-grid-enterprise/dist/types/core/entities/colDef").ValueGetterFunc<import("/home/rwilliams/repos/fifthsun/sentinel/src/api/mauthra/admin/Clients/common").Client, any> | undefined' is not assignable to type 'string | import("/home/rwilliams/repos/fifthsun/sentinel/node_modules/ag-grid-community/dist/types/core/entities/colDef").ValueGetterFunc<import("/home/rwilliams/repos/fifthsun/sentinel/src/api/mauthra/admin/Clients/common").Client, any> | undefined'.
          Type 'ValueGetterFunc<Client, any>' is not assignable to type 'string | ValueGetterFunc<Client, any> | undefined'.
            Type 'import("/home/rwilliams/repos/fifthsun/sentinel/node_modules/ag-grid-enterprise/dist/types/core/entities/colDef").ValueGetterFunc<import("/home/rwilliams/repos/fifthsun/sentinel/src/api/mauthra/admin/Clients/common").Client, any>' is not assignable to type 'import("/home/rwilliams/repos/fifthsun/sentinel/node_modules/ag-grid-community/dist/types/core/entities/colDef").ValueGetterFunc<import("/home/rwilliams/repos/fifthsun/sentinel/src/api/mauthra/admin/Clients/common").Client, any>'.
              Types of parameters 'params' and 'params' are incompatible.
                Type 'import("/home/rwilliams/repos/fifthsun/sentinel/node_modules/ag-grid-community/dist/types/core/entities/colDef").ValueGetterParams<import("/home/rwilliams/repos/fifthsun/sentinel/src/api/mauthra/admin/Clients/common").Client, any>' is not assignable to type 'import("/home/rwilliams/repos/fifthsun/sentinel/node_modules/ag-grid-enterprise/dist/types/core/entities/colDef").ValueGetterParams<import("/home/rwilliams/repos/fifthsun/sentinel/src/api/mauthra/admin/Clients/common").Client, any>'.
                  Types of property 'node' are incompatible.
                    Type 'import("/home/rwilliams/repos/fifthsun/sentinel/node_modules/ag-grid-community/dist/types/core/interfaces/iRowNode").IRowNode<import("/home/rwilliams/repos/fifthsun/sentinel/src/api/mauthra/admin/Clients/common").Client> | null' is not assignable to type 'import("/home/rwilliams/repos/fifthsun/sentinel/node_modules/ag-grid-enterprise/dist/types/core/interfaces/iRowNode").IRowNode<import("/home/rwilliams/repos/fifthsun/sentinel/src/api/mauthra/admin/Clients/common").Client> | null'.
                      Type 'import("/home/rwilliams/repos/fifthsun/sentinel/node_modules/ag-grid-community/dist/types/core/interfaces/iRowNode").IRowNode<import("/home/rwilliams/repos/fifthsun/sentinel/src/api/mauthra/admin/Clients/common").Client>' is not assignable to type 'import("/home/rwilliams/repos/fifthsun/sentinel/node_modules/ag-grid-enterprise/dist/types/core/interfaces/iRowNode").IRowNode<import("/home/rwilliams/repos/fifthsun/sentinel/src/api/mauthra/admin/Clients/common").Client>'.
                        Types of property 'setDataValue' are incompatible.
                          Type '(colKey: string | import("/home/rwilliams/repos/fifthsun/sentinel/node_modules/ag-grid-community/dist/types/core/entities/column").Column<any>, newValue: any, eventSource?: string | undefined) => boolean' is not assignable to type '(colKey: string | import("/home/rwilliams/repos/fifthsun/sentinel/node_modules/ag-grid-enterprise/dist/types/core/entities/column").Column<any>, newValue: any, eventSource?: string | undefined) => boolean'.
                            Types of parameters 'colKey' and 'colKey' are incompatible.
                              Type 'string | import("/home/rwilliams/repos/fifthsun/sentinel/node_modules/ag-grid-enterprise/dist/types/core/entities/column").Column<any>' is not assignable to type 'string | import("/home/rwilliams/repos/fifthsun/sentinel/node_modules/ag-grid-community/dist/types/core/entities/column").Column<any>'.
                                Type 'Column<any>' is not assignable to type 'string | Column<any>'.
                                  Type 'import("/home/rwilliams/repos/fifthsun/sentinel/node_modules/ag-grid-enterprise/dist/types/core/entities/column").Column<any>' is not assignable to type 'import("/home/rwilliams/repos/fifthsun/sentinel/node_modules/ag-grid-community/dist/types/core/entities/column").Column<any>'.
                                    Types have separate declarations of a private property 'gridOptionsService'.

EDIT:
I went and tried a few recent versions. v31.1.0 broke as well. However, v31.1.1 works!
Seems like they need to do some better quality control for their releases.

Searching to resolve the same issue, I came across your question. Thanks for the fix, it works for me. (I was coming from 30.2.1 and noticed that it was still broken in 31.2.1). 31.1.1 is the only version that is not reporting a type issue for column definitions.

The AgGrid team is now tracking this thanks to this issue here: https://github.com/ag-grid/ag-grid/issues/7899
The internal issue number is AG-11493. You can monitor it here: https://www.ag-grid.com/ag-grid-pipeline/
They said that a fix should get out with the next release, or possibly the one after that if it was too close to the cutoff.
